# Sending data from Dialog to Fragment

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

I am trying to send some data from a `DialogFragment` to a `TextView` from a `Fragment`.

After inserting the data in the available input and pressing SAVE, the app crashes.

I assume there is something wrong with the `IncomeDialogListener`.
I would appreciate some hints where I did wrong.

**This is the Dialog Class**

```
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_incomedialog, null);

    builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Add Income")
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String Amount = enter_income_amount.getText().toString();
                        String Note = enter_income_note.getText().toString();
                        String Date = enter_income_date.getText().toString();
                        incomeDialogListener.addDetails(Amount, Note, Date);



                }
            });

    enter_income_amount = view.findViewById(R.id.enter_income_amount);
    enter_income_note = view.findViewById(R.id.enter_income_note);
    enter_income_date = view.findViewById(R.id.enter_income_date);


    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try {
        incomeDialogListener = (IncomeDialogListener) getTargetFragment();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {

       throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + "Must Implement IncomeDialogListener");
    }
}

public interface IncomeDialogListener {

    void addDetails(String Amount, String Note, String Date);

}
```

**This is the Fragment to which I want to send the data**

```
    public class IncomeFragment extends Fragment implements 
    IncomeDialog.IncomeDialogListener {

DatabaseHelper myDB;
Button btn_add_income;
TextView display_income;

public IncomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_placeholder2 , container, false);

    display_income = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.display_income);
    btn_add_income = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_income);
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    btn_add_income.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           openIncomeDialog();
        }
    });

    return v;
}

private void openIncomeDialog() {

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    IncomeDialog incomeDialog = new IncomeDialog();
    incomeDialog.show(fragmentTransaction, "income dialog"    );

}

@Override
public void addDetails(String Amount, String Note, String Date) {
    display_income.setText(Amount);
}
}
```

Comment: Please include the error message / line number / and stacktrace of the crash to make this question easier to answer.

Comment: "incomeDialogListener.addDetails(Amount, Note, Date);" - please show how you assign a `value to incomeDialogListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution for you:
**IncomeFragment.java**

```
public static final int INCOME_DIALOG_FRAGMENT = 1; // Add this line

private void openIncomeDialog() {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    IncomeDialog incomeDialog = new IncomeDialog();
    incomeDialog.setTargetFragment(IncomeFragment.this, INCOME_DIALOG_FRAGMENT); // Add this line
    incomeDialog.show(fragmentTransaction, "income dialog");
}
```

**IncomeDialog.java**

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    String Amount = enter_income_amount.getText().toString();
    String Note = enter_income_note.getText().toString();
    String Date = enter_income_date.getText().toString();
    IncomeDialogListener listener = (IncomeDialogListener) getTargetFragment();
    listener.addDetails(Amount, Note, Date);
}
```

**Update:** There is no magic behind, when you open dialog from fragment, you passed itself to dialog by calling `setTargetFragment`. Then in the dialog you can refer to the fragment that opened it by calling `getTargetFragment`. Actually there are 2 solutions you can use.

```
IncomeFragment incomeFragment = (IncomeFragment) getTargetFragment();
incomeFragment.addDetails(Amount, Note, Date);
```

or

```
IncomeDialogListener listerner = (IncomeDialogListener) getTargetFragment();
listerner.addDetails(Amount, Note, Date);
```

I prefer to use the second one because the dialog don't need to know about specific fragment that opened it. This makes the dialog is usable. Imagine a situation, three days later, you would like to open the dialog from another fragment, in that case you don't need to modify the dialog again, just let the another fragment implements IncomeDialogListener. If you use the first one, you must go to the dialog and modify it to make sure it works for the another fragment.

Comment: IncomeFragment incomeFragment = (IncomeDialogListener) getTargetFragment(); It required incomeFragment, found incomeDialog.incomeDialogListener                              Tried to change to incomeDialogListerner incomedialoglistener = (IncomeDialogListener) getTargetFragment(); Now it works :)

Comment: Big thanks, but can you please tell me why? What is the logic behind?

Comment: Is it because of the onClick parameter "int which"?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate